# Unable to retrieve and set image from sqlite to ImageView in android

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I am trying to save an `Image` inside the `Sqlite` database in Android.I want to set that image on an `ImageView` after inserting it.  I tried with the following code but the image does not set. Can anyone tell me the problem with the code.

```
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Log.i("ic launcher byte array", ""+byteArray);
        db.insert_signature_table(String.valueOf(AssignedJobs.jobId), String.valueOf(AssignedJobs.teamId), byteArray);
        Log.i("get all signature data", ""+db.getAll_signature_table().get(0).get("sign"));
         byte[] bb = db.getAll_signature_table().get(0).get("sign").getBytes();
         Log.i("decodes", ""+bb);
         Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);
         edt_signature.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
```

**dbHelper class**

```
  query_signature_table = "CREATE TABLE signature_table(JobId STRING,TeamId STRING,sign BLOB)";
database.execSQL(query_signature_table);



public void insert_signature_table(String jobId, String teamId, byte[] imageInByte) {
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("JobId", jobId);
values.put("TeamId", teamId);
values.put("sign", imageInByte);

Log.i("values assigned", "" + imageInByte);

database.insert("signature_table", null, values);
database.close();
}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAll_signature_table() {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM signature_table";
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("JobId", cursor.getString(0));
        map.put("RigId", cursor.getString(1));

          byte[] temp_image = cursor.getBlob(2);

          map.put("sign",""+temp_image);

        wordList.add(map);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do that on the first place? **Save the image to  your usb storage** , save the **path of the file** in database, and then where ever you want to set the image, get the path of the image and set on the imageview voila................

Answer (score 0):

in one of my project i have saved image and retrieve it from database so i am sharing that code with you

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap getImageFromBytes(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

these are the methods that i have used to save and retrieve images from database and create the image field as BLOB ion your database

Answer (score 0):

This is work. Try It

```
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("JobId", cursor.getString(0));
    map.put("RigId", cursor.getString(1));

      byte[] temp_image = cursor.getBlob(2);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp_image , 0, temp_image .length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

      map.put("sign",""+bitmap);

    wordList.add(map);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```